# Is it possible to find source of module import?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I do know that `__name__` points to `'__main__'` if the module was called from the interpreter, and `modulename` when imported.

Say, I have this directory structure:

```
MyApp
  -> main.py
  -> foo.py
  -> tasks.py
```

Where `main.py` imports both `foo.py` and `tasks.py`

`tasks.py` does some file reads, it's considered totally fine when its imported from `main.py`

But on the other hand I have to run `celery` command outside, which calls the module as following:

> /MyApp $ celery -A tasks -l info

What I want to achieve is have an `IF` clause that checks if the `tasks.py` file was imported from `Celery` command or my `main.py` script and do file reads only when from the latter.

Is it possible to distinguish between them and have that file reads only when file is imported from my `main.py`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution for this lol, What I did was importing `sys` then checking `sys.argv`

```
>>> print(sys.argv)
['\\app\\.env\\Scripts\\celery', 'worker', '-A', 'tasks', '-l', 'info']
```

Later I can do:

```
if 'worker' in sys.argv:
   celery!
else:
   do file reads.
```

Any better solution is welcome!